Cannot get access token from EPIC Fhir API
I'm trying to get an access token from FHIR EPIC using JWT.  My code is below.  I keep getting this error
Request error: 400
Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token
I've tried looking at similar questions like Fhir Epic Sandbox : Using a JWT to Obtain an Access Token for a Backend Service. And I havent been able to get anywhere.
The apps that I created on vendor site are more than 3 weeks old.
I checked my JWT token on JWT.io and it seems to be rendering correctly. My expiration time should be around 3 minutes. I generate a new jti every time I run the script.
I tried to follow the OAuth2 documentation the best that I can. I'm hoping someone can lead me to the right direction.
def get_epoch_time():

current_epoch_seconds = int(time.time())

future_epoch_seconds = current_epoch_seconds + 180

 

return future_epoch_seconds

 

 

# function to read key certificate files

def get_key(path):

# open and read the file

with open(path,'rb') as file:

key_content = file.read()

#function to create kid (key identification)

#Key ID and is an identifier for the key used to sign a JWT.

def get_x509_fingerprint(cert_path):

"""

Calculates the SHA1 fingerprint of an X.509 certificate in colon-separated hex format.

"""

 

with open("../publickey509.pem", 'rb') as f:

cert_data = f.read()

 

cert_hash = hashlib.sha1(cert_data).digest()

return ':'.join(f'{byte:02x}' for byte in cert_hash)

 

cert_path = "../publickey509.pem" # Replace with the path to your certificate

fingerprint = get_x509_fingerprint(cert_path)

 

 

jti = str(uuid.uuid4())

print(jti, "my jti")

 

header = {

"alg": "RS384",

"typ": "JWT",

"kid" : fingerprint

 

}

 

payload = {

"iss": "${non_production_clientID}",

"sub": "${non_production_clientID}",

"aud": "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token",

"jti": jti,

"exp": get_epoch_time()

}

 

private_key = get_key("../privatekey.pem")

 

# create a signature for jwt token

private_signature = jwt.encode(header,payload,private_key)

 

print(private_signature)

 

 

post_body_data = {

"grant-type": "client_credentials",

"client_assertion_type" : "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",

"client_assertion" : private_signature

 

}

headers = {

'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

}

 

try:

auth_response = requests.post(base_auth_url,headers=headers, data = post_body_data)

auth_response.raise_for_status()

data = auth_response.json()

 

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

print(f"Request error: {e}")

 

except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:

print(f"JSON decoding error: {e}")

print(f"Response text: {auth_response.text}")


How does Epic know the public key to use to validate your signed JWT? Are you using a JSON Web Key Set hosted at a URL, or did you upload the public key to your app?

Hi Ashavan, Thank you for reply to my question. I don't understand your follow up questions.  For the public/private key I'm not sure. I followed the docs and they said generate your key on the local machine. I didn't see anything about uploading it to EPIC. I assumed it will be connected to client ID. I'm trying to make a backend services app

In order for Epic to be able to complete the authentication process, it has to validate the signed JWT you sent. It does this using the public key in your key pair. Epic has to have knowledge of this public key; the two ways for this to happen are by either uploading the public key for the sandbox in your app or providing a URL where you host a JWKS. If you haven't provided the public key in some way, that could very well be your issue.
